# JSON to HTML with jQuery (2 tables from 1 json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This jQuery code parse json data and create html table to div:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

const jsonData = $.getJSON("js/quotes.json");

function quotes(a, b) {
    (this.$div = $(a)),
         (this._quotes = b),
         (this._init = function () {
              var a = this;
              jsonData.then(function (b) {
                    if ("object" != typeof b) return !1;
                    var c = [];
                    a._quotes.forEach(function (a) {
                         (a = a.trim()),
                              b[a] &&
                                    c.push(
                                         '<tr data-name="' + b[a].code + '" class="' + b[a].movement + '"><td>' +
                                              b[a].code +
                                              '</td><td>' +
                                              b[a].bid +
                                              '</td><td>' +
                                              b[a].ask +
                                              '</td><td>' +
                                              b[a].spread +
                                              "</td></tr>"
                                    );
                    }),
                         c.length > 0 && a.$div.html("<table><tr><th>Symbol</th><th>Bid</th><th>Ask</th><th>Spread</th></tr>" + c.join("") + "</table>"),
                         setTimeout(a._init, 50e3);
              });
         }),
         this._init();
}

quotes("#quotes-block1", $("#quotes-block1").data("quotes1").split(","));
quotes("#quotes-block2", $("#quotes-block2").data("quotes2").split(","));

});
```

*HTML code:*

```
<div id="quotes-block1" data-quotes1="EUR/USD, GBP/USD, USD/CHF, USD/JPY"></div>
<div id="quotes-block2" data-quotes2="XRP/USD, LTC/USD"></div>
```

*Json:*

```
"XRP\/USD": {
        "bid": 0.5676,
        "ask": 0.5698,
        "type": "Cryptos",
        "code": "XRP\/USD",
        "mid": 0.5687,
        "movement": "down",
        "spread": 0.0022
    },
    "LTC\/USD": {
        "bid": 82.89,
        "ask": 83.72,
        "type": "Cryptos",
        "code": "LTC\/USD",
        "mid": 83.305,
        "movement": "down",
        "spread": 0.83
    },
    "ETH\/USD": {
        "bid": 588.62,
        "ask": 589.63,
        "type": "Cryptos",
        "code": "ETH\/USD",
        "mid": 589.125,
        "movement": "up",
        "spread": 1.01
    },
etc.
```

I need create table in div id="quotes-block1" and id="quotes-block2", but work only div id="quotes-block2"
What is my mistake? Help!

*Live example:*

1. json file: http://maxbeaub.bget.ru/json/js/quotes.json
2. jquery function: http://maxbeaub.bget.ru/json/js/quotes.js (get data from json and append table to div)
3. html result: http://maxbeaub.bget.ru/json/json.html (append table only to second div)

Answer (score 0):

The reason being is content being overwritten in second div only get referenced in an a.

```
   function quotes(a, b) {
    (this.$div = $(a)),
         (this._quotes = b),
         (this._init = function (div) { 
              var a = this; 
              jsonData.then(function (b) {
                    if ("object" != typeof b) return !1;
                    var c = [];
                    a._quotes.forEach(function (a) {
                         (a = a.trim()),
                              b[a] &&
                                    c.push(
                                         '<tr data-name="' + b[a].code + '" class="' + b[a].movement + '"><td>' +
                                              b[a].code +
                                              '</td><td>' +
                                              b[a].bid +
                                              '</td><td>' +
                                              b[a].ask +
                                              '</td><td>' +
                                              b[a].spread +
                                              "</td></tr>"
                                    );
                    }),
                         c.length > 0 && div.html("<table><tr><th>Symbol</th><th>Bid</th><th>Ask</th><th>Spread</th></tr>" + c.join("") + "</table>"),
                         setTimeout(a._init, 5e3);
              });
         }),
         this._init(this.$div);
```

Comment: in first div a = #quotes-block1, in second div a = #quotes-block2, why this dont work?

Comment: pretty clear that you setting a to this. that is a window when you call a.$div.html it always refers to second div, unless you find the div id from a. does that make sense?